# Why does e.target.src return undefined?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

How to swap image on clicked image which are in array (multiple images) on click using event listener?

I tried this:

```
let special_countries_element_image = document.getElementById("special_countries_element_image");

function changeImage(element,e) {

element.src = e.target.src
}
container_countries.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  changeImage(special_countries_element_image, e)

 });
```

I excpected that special_countries_element_image will store clicked image.
In console it shows this:
undefined:1
GET file:///C:/Users/admin/Desktop/site/undefined net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Please explain what mistake I made.

Comment: are you sure the thing getting clicked is an image element? Try printing out e.target and seeing what type of element it is

Comment: `console.log(e.target);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to accomplish with this code.

If you want to change an image on click I guess it's easier and better to add an onClick parameter on your images that when triggered calls a function that reads the current image and swaps the src with your newest image source.

It would be nice to also have your HTML code in the example that you've provided but I guess the problem of undefined on e.target.src is because you're trying to access an event on your container and not on your image component.